# Fresh install of elementary 7.1 makes requests to unresolvable/strange IP address blocks

Tags: networking

I installed a fresh copy of elementaryOs 7.1 and discovered that soon after logging in for the first time it started making requests to the internet.
Now - I can understand and reason canonical IPs and NTP requests, up to extent amazon (aws) and if really stretching, also google (tho it would be nice to know what exactly is this as well).

But what is making requests to Cloudflare and Fastly ?

I've tried running recursive grep over /etc (found nothing) and all files recursively (excluding /dev) searching for 151.101., but albeit being on a powerful machine with plenty of memory and fast SSD it has ran already for hours and not found anything yet.

Any ideas?

A list of sort | uniq'ed IPs it's bombing (bombing meaning trying to reach as I've essentially blocked it getting further from the router for now) is [here](https://pastebin.com/kcgVPWmz) (couldn't include post it here, stackexchange thought it to be spam)